# Error trying to add a web reference to dotnet core project. User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECA

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, web-reference

I have a dotnet core project that I need to a web reference to.  I select the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference provider and select the URL and click "Go"  The correct service shows up under the "services" window.  I change the namespace to something like mynewservice and press "finish."

The new window show adding connected service to project.
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of service endpoints found: 2
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Warning:Warning: Reference cannot be loaded: 'System.Data.Entity', Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
Updating project ...
Error:User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))
Done.
Error:Adding Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider to the project failed: User canceled out of save dialog (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004000C (OLE_E_PROMPTSAVECANCELLED))

What do I need to do to get the reference installed?  I've looked at previous examples and they usually indicate the proj file is locked but I can edit the proj file so it isn't locked.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to use ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Answer (score 1):

I never found an answer, however the method suddenly starting working and I no longer got the error. Not sure what changed but now it installs correctly.